# Exe is not downloaded from chrome web store for chrome browser version: 55

Tags: chrome-web-store

1. In chrome web store for “M-Files for Chrome” on clicking "Add to chrome", it has got successfully added in "chrome://extensions".
2. But see the difference it is creating, on clicking “Add to chrome” from chrome web store in chrome browser version: 54 and 55 (in the attached image).
3. In the image you could find all the files are downloaded from chrome web store except the application "M-Files-for-Chrome-1.0". This is the issue we are facing.

Or
Refer in the following path 
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User        Data\Default\Extensions\lapmgejioldofnecdomcdgblbiffefhb\1.6.10_0

If it is chrome browser version: 54 you could find the application "M-Files-for-Chrome-1.0" downloaded in the above path.
If it is chrome browser version:55 the application will not exist. This is the issue.

I would like to know why this application (M-Files-for-Chrome-1.0) alone got skipped in chrome browser version:55 alone. And got successfully downloaded for chrome browser version:54.
Due to this the end user is facing “File Not Found” issue if they are using chrome browser version: 55.

Kindly guide me. And reply as soon as possible.

[Chrome browser version 54](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOuRo.png)

[Chrome browser version 55](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD9vN.png)